# npm install not installing the packages on a git repo clone. (giving no-replace-object and cannot store pack file error)

Tags: npm, loopback, pack

trying to clone a git repo which has several npm dependencies, but it is failing with a pack error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x56F.png)